# Dúvida de como utilizar uma classe Less com RAZOR

Tags: css, css3, less

Eu estou pesquisando um pouco pra implementar uma funcionalidade pra facilitar a vida na hora de programar.

**É possível fazer isso?**

Estamos usando o VS2013 com **razor**.

Eu tenho a seguinte classe Less:

```
.minColuna(@a) {
    -webkit-min-width: @a;
    -moz-min-width: @a;
    -ms-min-width: @a;
    -o-min-width: @a;
    min-width:  @a;
}
```

E não consigo chamar o método assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O Razor faz com que ele não consiga identificar o @a como uma variável e por causa disso buga.
Eu já tentei fazer isso por JS colocando a classe na table mas deu o mesmo problema...
E já tentei usando isso:

```
class="minColuna(@Html.Raw("@a"): 300px)"
```

Mas ele não pega o estilo :/

É possível contornar esse bug?

Ou até mesmo existe algo dentro do JQuery / JS / LESS / HTML que possa fazer algo assim pra mim?

Comment: Se vai parametrizar tag por tag, por que não utiliza o `style` ? `<th style="min-width:300px;"`

Comment: porque eu não vou fazer isso, eu simplifiquei o máximo possível pro exemplo. Vou usar isso em um dataTable no JS

Comment: Mas isso é realmente possível de fazer? Que eu saiba o less tem que ser compilado para css para funcionar, mesmo usando o `less.js` ele vai funcionar com arquivos linkados ou tags `style` incluídos no html com o `type="text\less"`, mas nunca ouvi falar que poderia usar direto em um atributo `class`, principalmente porque o que você está tentando usar nem ao menos é uma `class`, ele é um mixin parametrizado

Comment: Não sei se é possível fazer, por isso eu vim perguntar aqui

Answer (score 2):

Veja dessa forma. Cria uma classe que chama sua função com o valor do param.

```
.tamanhoColuna(@x){
    min-width: @x;
}

.chamaFuncao {
  .tamanhoColuna(10px);
}

<p class="chamaFuncao"> Teste :D </p>
```

### Atenção

Você não vai conseguir passar o valor em tempo real, a não ser que compile o `LESS` em tempo real.

Comment: a questão é que eu quero poder enviar o valor na hora que eu colocar a class, pq aqui na empresa não podemos ficar mexendo muito no CSS do sistema

Comment: O Less precisa ser compilado em CSS. Você terá que fazer a compilação *runtime*, então. Ou trocar de empresa. Porquê os caras pedem pra alterar o site, mas não deixa mexer no código... TRETA HEIN!

Answer (score 1):

Tente o seguinte:

```
.tamanhoColuna(@x){
    min-width: @x;
}

<p class="tamanhoColuna(@x: 200px)"> Teste :D </p>
```

Comment: parceiro obrigado pela ajuda, mas não deu certo. Editei o tópico, pode olhar ali?

Answer (score 0):

Já existe essa funcionalidade no HTML, ela é bastante conhecida como CSS *inline*.

**Exemplo:**

```css
th {background-color:#444; color:#FFF;}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th style="min-width:80px;">Col 1</th>
    <th style="min-width:160px;">Col 2</th>
    <th style="min-width:320px;">Col 3</th>
    <th style="min-width:640px;">Col 4</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

<sub>Obs.: O que você está tentando fazer não é nem tentando reinventar a roda, mas sim a pedra. Evite esse tipo de coisa, mas se não tiver como, aqui vai um [exemplo de trabalho manual](https://jsfiddle.net/tcfxg4j9/).</sub>